# php - sql, get user id after login form by using $_session

Tags: php, sql, session, login-control

i am try to assign the user id in a $_session after login from login page.
I have read many posts here but i can unterstand how its work.

[Here is my db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caOVM.jpg)

Here is my code from login.php

```
<?php
session_start(); //Έναρξη session
require_once('connect.php'); //καλώ το αρχείο
//Τι γίνετε όταν submitted η φόρμα
if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){

//Αναθέση τιμών μεταβλητών από τα inputs
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

//Έλεγχος αν υπάρχουν τα στοιχεία σύνδεσης στην βάση
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `usermanagement` WHERE username ='$username' AND password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count == 1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['UserId'] = $userid; // <-trying to determine this variable
}else{
    $fmsg = "Λάθος Όνομα Χρήστη ή Κωδικό χρήστη. ";
}
}
?>
```

i saw that `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` but i don' t know how to do something similar for `$_SESSION['userid'] = $userId;`

Any help? Even a link.

Comment: you need to fetch the user id from the query. Also you need PHP MYSQL tutorials to get the proper foundation. Getting free code won't help you learn

Comment: You haven't defined `$userid`. You can't use a value from a variable that doesn't exist. You should work through some basic examples like [those in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php) to understand how to use the results of your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the results from the sql query and use that to get the `userid`

```
if( $count == 1 ){

    /* there is a recordset so fetch into as array */
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );

    /* extract the required variables from recordset array */
    $userid=$row['userid'];

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['UserId'] = $userid; // <-this variable should now exist

}else{
    $fmsg = "Λάθος Όνομα Χρήστη ή Κωδικό χρήστη. ";
}
```

Comment: Just remember that colum name is idUser